# How can i prevent connection from clients using TLS less than v1.2?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, deprecated

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_server_method());
```

I get a warning for this that tells me that TLSv1_2_server_method is deprecated and i should use the general TLS_server_method and let the client & server negotiate what they want to use. I don't want this as i write both the server and the client side and i want to filter attacks using earlier versions' bugs (surfaced in the future). I know i'm just being paranoid and i can ignore the deprecation warning for now, but i want to use my best options and "for now" is not enough for me. So is there a possibility to somehow force OpenSSL not to allow < v1.2 TLS clients to connect, or its developers just made the wrong decision and took it away completely?
(Debian 9.3, libssl-dev 1.1.0f-3+deb9u1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just read the [doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/TLSv1_2_server_method.html) since it answers this question

> If you want to limit the supported protocols for the version flexible
>   methods you can use SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version,
>   SSL_set_min_proto_version, SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version and
>   SSL_set_max_proto_version functions.